# Point Jenkins Robot plugin to store logs at different path in master node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

By default Jenkins Robot Plugin collects log files from Slave machine (Where robot tests run) to Master Node at certain location and read the logs and display Robot framework Test summary.

But I want to maintain seperate log server to store all the logs instead of storing in it master.

And I couldn't see any option to point to different server or path.

I have created a mount path to log server in Jenkins master, but no option found to point out robot plugin to store the logs at mount path, read data from logs and view all statistics related to PASS/FAIL count.